# MVC Create: Submit without clearing form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, model-view-controller

It has been a while since I was in school for this, but looking for some help on a project I am working on in my spare time.

I have an MVC project in which I am currently working with a Create page.  I would like to maintain the selections and inputs after submission.  In general, I would like to be able to submit a form without anything refreshing so I can limit the selections for the next one.

This page is to add a security camera to the database.  I may need to add several cameras and would like to limit the data entry.  So keep the inputs after I hit the submit button and just make changes and then submit again.

Comment: If you submit the form, the page is gone... if you want to display the same data, you need to reload it. Your question is too broad and it is difficult to help you... one thing to keep in mind is that you don't have to submit the form... as an example, you can make an ajax call to the server without refreshing the page.

Comment: It is all about JavaScript to request resources - AJAX Please read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/contact-manager/iteration-7-add-ajax-functionality-cs